# SQL - Compare 2 tables with dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables with are the following:

```
st with an id, startDate, endDate, customer_id and serivcedeal_Id.

servicedeal with id and name.

price with id, price, startDate and servicedeal_Id.
```

I have the following data in the tables:

wpwh_veosoft_crm_st

[image: Table st]

wpwh_veosoft_crm_servicedeal

[image: Table servicedeal]

wpwh_veosoft_crm_price

[image: Table price]

If i have the following data:

table st

```
startDate = 2018-11-01
endDate = 2019-03-05
customer_Id = 355
Servicedeal_Id = 3
```

table servicedeal

```
id = 3 
name = lille pakke
```

i only want to see the row with id 13 from table price because its the closet date before my startDate 2018-11-01

Does anyone have an SQL that can solve the problem?

thanks in advance

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join and filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*, d.*, p.*
from wpwh_veosoft_crm_st s
inner join wpwh_veosoft_crm_servicedeal d on d.id = s.servicedeal_id
inner join wpwh_veosoft_crm_price p on p.servicedeal_id = s.servicedeal_id
where p.startDate = (
    select max(p1.startDate)
    from wpwh_veosoft_crm_price p1
    where p1.servicedeal_id = s.servicedeal_id and p1.startDate < s.startDate
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the price id using a correlated subquery:

```
select st.*,
       (select p.id
        from price p
        where p.Servicedeal_Id = st.Servicedeal_Id and
              p.startDate <= st.startDate
        order by p.startDate desc
        limit 1
       ) as price_id
from st;
```

If you want additional information, you can `join` it in, using this as a subquery or CTE.  If you only want the price, you can just select that column instead of the id.

This type of query can be resource-intensive.  You might want an index on `price(Servicedeal_Id, startDate, id)`.